# Longest subarray that has a sum equal to s

Tags: python, arrays, algorithm, performance, time-complexity

How can I speed up my implementation of the problem statement below? I have a correct solution that passes every test for small inputs. However, it exceeds the time limits for larger inputs. My current implementation is quadratic in the size of the array.

**Problem statement**

You have an unsorted `array` arr of non-negative integers and a number `s`. Find a longest contiguous subarray in `arr` that has a sum equal to `s`. Return two integers that represent its inclusive bounds. If there are several possible answers, return the one with the smallest left bound. If there are no answers, return [-1].

Your answer should be 1-based, meaning that the first position of the array is 1 instead of 0.

**Implementation**

```
def findLongestSubarrayBySum(s, arr):
    """Return a two-element array that represent the bounds of the subarray."""
    ans = [-1]

    for left in range(len(arr)):
        curr_sum = arr[left]
        if curr_sum == s and len(ans) == 1:
            ans = [left + 1] * 2

        for right in range(left + 1, len(arr)):
            curr_sum += arr[right]

            if curr_sum == s:
                # First found soltion
                if len(ans) == 1:
                    ans = [left + 1, right + 1]
                # Left bound is right bound
                elif ans[1] == ans[0]:
                    ans = [left + 1, right + 1]
                # Longer subarray
                elif ans[1] - ans[0] < right - left:
                    ans = [left + 1, right + 1]

            elif curr_sum > s:
                break

    return ans


if __name__ == '__main__':

    # s = 12  # ans = [2, 4]
    # arr = [1, 2, 3, 7, 5]

    # s = 15  # ans = [1, 5]
    # arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    # s = 15  # ans = [1, 8]
    # arr = [1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 0, 0, 0, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10]

    # s = 3   # ans = -1
    # arr = [1, 1]

    # s = 3   # ans = -1
    # arr = [2]

    # s = 468    # ans = [42, 46]
    # arr = [135, 101, 170, 125, 79, 159, 163, 65, 106, 146, 82, 28,
    #         162, 92, 196, 143, 28, 37, 192, 5, 103, 154, 93, 183, 22,
    #         117, 119, 96, 48, 127, 0, 172, 0, 139, 0, 0, 70, 113, 68,
    #         100, 36, 95, 104, 12, 123, 134]

    # s = 3  # ans = [1, 1]
    # arr = [3]

    # s = 0     # ans = [2, 2]
    # arr = [1, 0, 2]

    s = 3    # ans = [1, 3]
    arr = [0, 3, 0]

    print(findLongestSubarrayBySum(s, arr))
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's an implementation of the two-pointer approach that's linear in time and constant in extra space overhead. It's similar to your solution, except we don't regrow the window from size 0 on every loop iteration. Since you only want the earliest, largest window, the right pointer only ever increases (rather than increase and decrease), making the time complexity easy to prove.

```py
def findLongestSubarrayBySum(s, arr):
    """Return a two-element array that represent the bounds of the subarray."""
    ans = [-1, -2]
    s -= arr[0]
    right = 0
    for left in range(len(arr)):
        while right < len(arr) - 1 and s >= arr[right + 1]:
            s -= arr[right + 1]
            right += 1
        if s == 0 and right - left > ans[-1] - ans[0]:
            ans = [left + 1, right + 1]
        s += arr[left]
    if ans[0] == -1:
        return [-1]
    return ans
```

Comment: Could a sequence that starts by incrementing the right pointer, then increasing the left pointer, alternating each, result in a wrong solution?

Comment: @גלעדברקן It depends what you mean exactly; the second proposed algorithm in your answer is correct and essentially what this implements. I just wrote up an implementation since the other answer's link solves a different problem.

Comment: Oh, ok. Cool, tx!

Answer (score 4):

If the input contains negative numbers, use prefix sums conceptually and a hash table in practice. `prefixes_j - prefixes_i = s`. For each `prefixes_j`, which is simply a single, accumulating sum, check if the key, `prefixes_j - s`, exists in the hash table; after that, if the sum doesn't exist in the table, insert it as a key pointing to the current index. The value stored at that key will be the first index where that prefix sum was seen, that way, the leftmost index is returned for duplicates.

```
[1, 2, 3, 7, 5]  s = 12

sum 1
hash 1

sum 3
hash 1, 3

sum 6
hash 1, 3, 6

sum 13
hash contains 1
found 13 - 12 = 1
record length 3

etc...
```

If the input doesn't contain negative numbers, use the idea that the right pointer can stop as soon as the sum exceeds s, then increment the left pointer until it's smaller again, alternating pointer increments that way, so each pointer traverses the list once in total.

Comment: Your first solution does not solve the problem any more efficiently than the OP's since you would have to repeat the process for every starting index *i* to find the longest sub-sequence in the given list.

Comment: @blhsing flat wrong. First, the question is looking for subarray, not subsequence. Second, each operation is O(1), and we traverse the list once, which together is O(n), which is optimal.

Answer (score 0):

You may use two pointer method whose time complexity will be `O(n)` and space complexity will be `O(1)`. A similar problem and two pointer solution can be found [here](https://webrewrite.com/subarray-with-given-sum/).

Comment: Not if the input contains negative numbers.

Comment: Oh, but it says the input doesn't contain negative numbers,  ha!

Comment: Yes but in this case, the input includes only non-negative integers.

Comment: Yes, I added that alternative to my answer.